# Move to new Macbook - IOS App Push Notification and certificate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apns-php

I need to amend an existing IOS project build by previous developer on my macbook.

The app is currently live in app store and using Apple Push Services Certificate (Production certificate)

So, in xcode, i want to run / amend / test the app using stimulator, but i got error, and need to configure the signing first.

I need to make sure while amending the app, the current app with push notification at app store still function as usual.

[Apple developer account page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zr1X.jpg)

[xcode signing & capabilities setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOQ5A.jpg)

1. if i tick the "Automatically manage signing" at xcode as shown picture above, and select the team account, will it affect or revoke or regenerate the current active Apple Push Services Certificate (production) at the apple developer account?
2. or can i use manual configuration, without using the "Automatically manage signing"?
3. Since i'm using another computer to run the app, currently i did not transfer any certificate from the old mac to new macbook, do i need to transfer certificate if using the "Automatically manage signing"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Certificates and profiles are needed when you build your app on real device or upload to AppStoreConnect. In this case you need to download and install provisioning profiles from your apple developer account page, then import your p12 certificates from KeyChain on your old macbook and transfer them to new. 
In case of usage of manual signing don't forget to check certs and profiles in build settings menu.
Also you can build and run app at simulator without them. But only on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers to your questions:

1. if i tick the "Automatically manage signing" at xcode as shown picture above, and select the team account, will it affect or revoke or regenerate the current active Apple Push Services Certificate (production) at the apple developer account?

Answer: **No, it won't affect the current active certificates. It will just create new set of certificate and profiles for you. However, Avoid using automatic signing if possible.**

2. can i use manual configuration, without using the "Automatically manage signing"?

Answer: **Yes, Thats what @dmytro also suggesting you to do. I prefer to use manual configuration. For this, you need to export both the public & private key of the certificates from your previous Macbook as p12. You can install these p12 files in the keychain of your current Macbook then. Similary, you can download the already created provisioning profiles.**

3. Since i'm using another computer to run the app, currently i did not transfer any certificate from the old mac to new macbook, do i need to transfer certificate if using the "Automatically manage signing"?

Answer: No, you don't need to transfer previous certificates if you are using automatic signing.

Please also note that, you may also create new certificates and profiles and that wont affect the already live build.